# Array size of things

Tags: arrays

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    $$  \begin{array}{cl}
        f(\hat{x}_n) & =\displaystyle  \int_{-1}^{0} \hat{x}_n d t  - \int_{0}^{1} \hat{x}_n d t  \\
         & = \displaystyle  \int_{-1}^{-\frac{1}{n+1}} d t   +\int_{-\frac{1}{n+1}}^{0} -(n+1)t d t   +\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n+1}} (n+1)t d t  +\int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{1} d t \\
         & =\frac{n}{n+1} +\frac{n}{2n+21} +\frac{n}{2n+2}  +\frac{n}{n+1} \\
         & = \frac{2n+1}{n+1} 
    \end{array}
    $$
\end{document}
```

This gave me the following:
[image]

And this very ugly, the size of the fractions is too small, if I change it they overlapse, the same space of the lines is very small for the integrals to look good. How can I improve this?

Comment: You could use an `align` environment.

Comment: note that `$$` is not latex (use `\[..\]`) the `array` environment is designed for arrays/matrices of values not for displayed equations so they are set in textsyle and the spacing is all wrong, which is why you are needing to ty to correct with `\displaystyle` but better to use a display environment such as `align` (or `aligned` for a term within a larger display)

Answer (score 2):

With  `align` for numbered lines and `align*` for unnumbered lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 f(\hat{x}_n) & = \int_{-1}^{0} \hat{x}_n d t  - \int_{0}^{1} \hat{x}_n d t  \\
              & = \int_{-1}^{-\frac{1}{n+1}} d t   +\int_{-\frac{1}{n+1}}^{0} -(n+1)t d t   
                  +\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n+1}} (n+1)t d t  +\int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{1} d t \\
              & =\frac{n}{n+1} +\frac{n}{2n+21} +\frac{n}{2n+2}  +\frac{n}{n+1} \\
              & = \frac{2n+1}{n+1} 
\end{align}


\begin{align*}
 f(\hat{x}_n) & = \int_{-1}^{0} \hat{x}_n d t  - \int_{0}^{1} \hat{x}_n d t  \\
              & = \int_{-1}^{-\frac{1}{n+1}} d t   +\int_{-\frac{1}{n+1}}^{0} -(n+1)t d t   
                  +\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n+1}} (n+1)t d t  +\int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{1} d t \\
              & =\frac{n}{n+1} +\frac{n}{2n+21} +\frac{n}{2n+2}  +\frac{n}{n+1} \\
              & = \frac{2n+1}{n+1} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```